3D object rotation based on tensorflow handpose landmarks
So I am currently working on a project that is using @tensorflow-models/handpose to detect hand landmarks and then I am matching the x and y of the landmark 0 to a 3d model. However. I am using info to try to match the rotations of my hand wit the 3d object's rotation. however what I can't figure out is:
when for example I hold my hand vertically and then rotate it around itself the watch rotates with it, however when I do it horizontally the watch seems to rotate badly. also as you can figure out I think when i translate my hand from vertical to horizontal my watch(3D) object is also rotating around the z axis.
I am stuck with this for a while now and don't know what to do. Any help would be really appreciated.
Here is the code:
<body>
    <video id="video" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <canvas id="output"></canvas>
    <canvas id="three-canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        const video = document.getElementById('video');
        const canvas = document.getElementById('output');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const threeCanvas = document.getElementById('three-canvas');
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: threeCanvas, alpha: true });

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.position.z = 10;

        // Add lighting
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // Soft white light
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 1).normalize();
        scene.add(directionalLight);

        // Load the watch model
        const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        let watchModel;

        // Load the textures
        const diffuseMap = textureLoader.load('{% static "textures/1/1_21068718-f0cmplp9luxiysskijb2s9xb-ExtraLarge.jpg" %}', function(texture) {
            console.log("Diffuse map loaded successfully");
        }, undefined, function(error) {
            console.error("Error loading diffuse map:", error);
        });

        const roughnessMap = textureLoader.load('{% static "textures/1/1_Clay004_2K_Roughness.jpg" %}', function(texture) {
            console.log("Roughness map loaded successfully");
        }, undefined, function(error) {
            console.error("Error loading roughness map:", error);
        });

        const bodyEmissionMap = textureLoader.load('{% static "textures/1/1_rolex_body_Emission.png" %}', function(texture) {
            console.log("Body emission map loaded successfully");
        }, undefined, function(error) {
            console.error("Error loading body emission map:", error);
        });

        const dialEmissionMap = textureLoader.load('{% static "textures/1/1_rolex_dial_Emission.png" %}', function(texture) {
            console.log("Dial emission map loaded successfully");
        }, undefined, function(error) {
            console.error("Error loading dial emission map:", error);
        });

        loader.load("{% static '1.glb' %}", function(gltf) {
            watchModel = gltf.scene;

            watchModel.traverse((child) => {
                if (child.isMesh) {
                    child.material.map = diffuseMap;
                    child.material.roughnessMap = roughnessMap;
                    child.material.emissiveMap = bodyEmissionMap;
                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                    
                    // Apply the dial emission map to the dial part of the model
                    if (child.name.includes("dial")) { // Assuming "dial" in the name for differentiation
                        child.material.emissiveMap = dialEmissionMap;
                    }
                }
            });

            watchModel.scale.set(20, 20, 20); // Adjust the scale as needed
            scene.add(watchModel);
        }, undefined, function(error) {
            console.error("Error loading GLTF model:", error);
        });

        async function setupCamera() {
            const isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

            let constraints = {
                video: {
                    facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
                }
            };

            if (isMobile) {
                constraints.video.width = { ideal: 1920 };
                constraints.video.height = { ideal: 1080 };
            }

            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
                video.srcObject = stream;
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.name === 'OverconstrainedError') {
                    console.warn('OverconstrainedError: Trying to use default resolution constraints');
                    constraints = {
                        video: true
                    };
                    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    throw error;
                }
            }

            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                    resolve(video);
                };
            });
        }

        async function main() {
            await setupCamera();
            video.play();

            const net = await handpose.load();
            console.log('Handpose model loaded.');

            function resizeCanvas() {
                canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
                canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            }

            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
            video.addEventListener('loadeddata', resizeCanvas);
            resizeCanvas();

            let lastFrameTime = 0;
            const frameRate = 30; // Limit to 30 frames per second

            function calculateAngle(v1, v2) {
                return Math.atan2(v2.y - v1.y, v2.x - v1.x);
            }

            async function detectHands() {
                const now = Date.now();
                const elapsed = now - lastFrameTime;

                if (elapsed > (1000 / frameRate)) {
                    lastFrameTime = now;

                    const predictions = await net.estimateHands(video);
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                    if (predictions.length > 0) {
                        predictions.forEach(prediction => {
                            const landmarks = prediction.landmarks;

                            const wrist = landmarks[0];
                            const middleFinger = landmarks[9]; // Use the base of the middle finger for orientation
                            const indexFinger = landmarks[5]; // Use the base of the index finger for rotation calculation

                            const x = (wrist[0] - video.videoWidth / 2) / 500; // Adjust the x offset as needed
                            const y = -(wrist[1] - video.videoHeight / 2) / 500; // Adjust the y offset as needed
                            const z = 0; // Adjust z scaling for visibility

                            if (watchModel) {
                                watchModel.position.set(x, y, z);

                                // Calculate the angle of rotation based on the wrist and middle finger
                                const angle = calculateAngle(
                                    { x: wrist[0], y: wrist[1] },
                                    { x: middleFinger[0], y: middleFinger[1] }
                                );

                                // Calculate the angle for hand rotation around the z-axis
                                const rotationAngle = calculateAngle(
                                    { x: indexFinger[0], y: indexFinger[1] },
                                    { x: middleFinger[0], y: middleFinger[1] }
                                );

                                // Apply the rotation
                                watchModel.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, -Math.PI / 2 - angle, -rotationAngle);
                            }

                            ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
                            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

                            for (let i = 0; i < landmarks.length; i++) {
                                const [x, y] = landmarks[i];
                                ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                                ctx.fill();
                            }

                            const fingerConnections = [
                                [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4],
                                [0, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8],
                                [5, 9], [9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12],
                                [9, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16],
                                [13, 17], [17, 18], [18, 19], [19, 20],
                                [0, 17]
                            ];

                            ctx.beginPath();
                            fingerConnections.forEach(pair => {
                                const [start, end] = pair;
                                ctx.moveTo(landmarks[start][0], landmarks[start][1]);
                                ctx.lineTo(landmarks[end][0], landmarks[end][1]);
                            });
                            ctx.stroke();
                        });
                    }
                }

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                requestAnimationFrame(detectHands);
            }

            detectHands();
        }

        main();
    </script>
</body>

Also I must mention I tried using rotation matrices and even quaternions but with no success. I get the same errors.
Thank you!

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
